# getServerSideProps перестал работать сразу на нескольких страницах

Tags: javascript, reactjs, клиент-сервер, nextjs, данные

У меня в [id].jsx я получал данные с помощью getSer... и в один момент он перестал работать

```js
export default function Container({ account = 'loading' }) {
  console.log(account)

  return <h1>Lorem</h1>
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  return {
    props: {
      account: 'Lorem ipsum dolar'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Что за ошибка то? В каком месте происходит?

Comment: Ошибки нет, просто не работает getServerSideProps

Comment: Так не бывает. Он вызывается вообще? Возвращает объект? Попробуйте обернуть return в try catch с выводом в консоль ошибки. Может чего ломается

Comment: catch не сработал

Comment: Единственное место, которое может быть с ошибкой в getServerSideProps - это query.id, если на вход был передан не объект(null | undefined к примеру)

Comment: Я его комментировал и все равно не работал

Comment: Покажите кусок кода, как вы вызываете getServerSideProps и что он возвращает

Comment: Как изменить вопрос

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "править" или изменить

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Component {...pageProps} />
```

Я решил эту проблему, у меня в _app.jsx в  не передавался {...pageProps}